PowerShell Class Method return Type as parameter (like JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize)
I'm trying to build a Method inside a Class, that accepts the required return type as a parameter. An example of this, is the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer Class, Deserialize Method. It takes two parameters, A JSON text and the return type that it is expected to return. If I were to do something like below, and provided the $JSONConect contains valid information about the Class I want to use, I get a proper Object of type [Test]
$JSSerializer   = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$JSONObject     = [MyData]::New( )
If( $JSONContent -ne $null )
{
    $JSONObject     = $JSSerializer.Deserialize( $JSONContent, [MyData] )
}


I have tried building something this, but I get errors on the return type.
class Test
{
    [Type] TestType( [Type]$AParam )
    {
        Write-Host "Your provided the type  : $AParam"

        $Result = New-Object $AParam

        Write-Host "Your provided the value : $Result"

        Switch( $AParam )
        {
            "bool"
            {
                Write-Host "Your provided the type  : `"Boolean`""
                $Result = $True
            }
            "int"
            {
                Write-Host "Your provided the type  : `"Integer`""
                $Result = 2
            }
            "string"
            {
                Write-Host "Your provided the type  : `"String`""
                $Result = "Miep"
            }
            Default
            {
                Write-Host "Your provided the type  : `"Invalid!`""
                $Result = $null
            }
        }

        #$Result = [$AParam.GetType( )]
        #return $Result

        #return [Type]$( $AParam )
        return Write-Output -NoEnumerate $Result
    }
}

[bool]$tBool     = $False
[int]$tInt       = 0
[string]$tString = ""


$MyTest = [Test]::New( )

$tBool   = $MyTest.TestType( [bool] )
$tBool

exit
$tInt    = $MyTest.TestType( [int] )
$tInt

$tString = $MyTest.TestType( [string] )
$tString

#$MyTest.TestType( $tBool )
#$MyTest.TestType( $tInt )
#$MyTest.TestType( $tString )


The code above works partially, I can provide just a Type as parameter. But it will not return anything. As you can see, I have tried three ways to get this working, but I keep getting errors.
With the code as-is above, I get the following error:
Your provided the type  : bool
Your provided the value : False
Your provided the type: "Boolean"
Cannot convert value "True" to type "System.Type". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Type'."
At D:\ParameterTypePassingUsng.ps1:39 char:16
+         return Write-Output -NoEnumerate $Result
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible
 
False


Any suggestions on how to get this work, if it's at all possible? I cannot do this with CmdLets, because I just reworked my entire library to use classes instead of a collection of separate functions.

Your signature says you are returning a Type but you're actually returning a value. Seems like you actually want to return an Object to dynamically output either int, string or bool

What problem are trying to solve? PowerShell doesn't support generic type parameters in type definitions, so the solution is indeed to use [object] as the return type - but it also doesn't really matter much, PowerShell is much more concerned with runtime types than method signatures

I am trying to get something to work, similar to the Deserialize Method, and thanks to your help, I got what I wanted. I changed the return type to [object] and it works as intended.

Hinted out by Mathias, what seemed you were looking for is known as Generic Methods in C# however PowerShell classes don't support this feature.
The error is telling you that in your method signature you're stating that the method will take a Type as input and return a Type as output and you aren't fulfilling this contract since you're returning the instance of a type or $null (int, string, bool or $null).
By changing the signature to return type of [object] the code would work properly:
[object] TestType([Type] $AParam)

You also will need to remove Write-Output -NoEnumerate, just return $result otherwise in PowerShell 7+ you will get unexpected return type of List<object>, for example:
(Write-Output 1 -NoEnumerate).GetType() # List<object>

It's also unclear what you want to do with $Result = New-Object $AParam, should be removed.
In summary the definition should be:
class Test {
    [Object] TestType([Type] $AParam) {
        Write-Host "You provided the type  : $AParam"
        $Result = $null
        switch ($AParam) {
            ([bool]) {
                Write-Host "You provided the type  : `"Boolean`""
                $Result = $True
            }
            ([int]) {
                Write-Host "You provided the type  : `"Integer`""
                $Result = 2
            }
            ([string]) {
                Write-Host "You provided the type  : `"String`""
                $Result = 'Miep'
            }
            Default {
                Write-Host "You provided the type  : `"Invalid!`""
            }
        }
        return $Result
    }
}

Using Generics in C# the code could be something like:
public static class Test
{
    public static T? TestType<T>()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        object? result = type switch
        {
            _ when type == typeof(bool) => true,
            _ when type == typeof(int) => 2,
            _ when type == typeof(string) => "Miep",
            _ => null
        };

        Console.WriteLine(
            $"You provided the type  : '{result?.GetType().Name ?? "Invalid!"}'");

        return (T?)result;
    }
}

